# The figure will be elongated when adjust Axes3D.set_zlim

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D  # noqa: F401 unused import

# setup the figure and axes
bottom=np.zeros_like(xx)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 8))  # 画布宽长比例
ax1= fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
# ax2= fig.add_subplot(132, projection='3d')
# ax3= fig.add_subplot(133, projection='3d')

ax1.bar3d(xx-0.5, yy+0.5, bottom,0.7 , 0.7, z3, color=C3,shade=True)
# ax1.set_xticks([i+0.15 for i in xx])
ax1.set_xticklabels(labels)
ax1.set_yticklabels(labels)
# the adjust operation is here
# ax1.set_zlim(bottom=0.8,top=1.0)
ax1.set_title("ARI")
plt.savefig("1.png")
```

before I adjust zlim,the figure is showing as follow,
[image]

but!! I uncomment the ax1.set_zlim(bottom=0.8,top=1.0), the figure change as follow,
[image]

**If I wanna to erase the bottom of image, what should I do?**

Answer (score 0):

The solution is following

```
#change the bard3d to this
ax1.bar3d(xx-0.5, yy+0.5, z3,0.7 , 0.7,-(z3-0.9), color=C3,shade=True)
```

because bar3d(x,y,z,w,h,d),x,y,z deside the coordinates at the bottom of the cylinder ,when z=z3( float list), then we need set to be a negative number.